# Finding closed subspace for a linear operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a real Hilbert space and $P:X \rightarrow X$ be a linear operator satisfies a) $P^2=P$,

b) $P$ continuous,

c) $(Px,y)=(x,Py)$.

Show that there is $M \subset X$ closed linear subspace such that $P$ is the orthogonal projection $P_M$ onto $M.$

My attempt:

Define $N=\{x\in X: Px=0\}=P^{-1}(\{0\})$, so if $Px \neq 0$ for all $x \in X$, then set $M=\{0\}.$ By (b) $P^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed, and let us assume that there are some $x \in X$ such that $Px=0.$ I can not go forther from here, how can I use a,c properties?

Thanks for any help with that.

Comment: How do you define orthogonal projection?

Answer (score 1):

Let $N=P^{-1}(0)$, and $M$ the orthogonal to $N$, we have $x=x-P(x)+P(x)$, let $u=x-P(x), P(u)=0$ so $u\in N$,  we need to show that $P(x)\in M$, for every $v\in N$, $P(v)=0$ implies that $\langle v,P(x)\rangle=\langle P(v),x\rangle=0$. This implies that $P(x)\in M$.